# MySQL query matching multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm confused on how to write the following query in MySQL: Given one collaborator, I'd like to get all the collaborators that participated on each item that this collaborator worked on.

Here's my collaborators table:

```
id collaborator_id item_id
1      1              1
2      2              1
3      3              1
4      4              2
5      1              2
6      2              3
```

for collaborator_id=1, the query would return:

```
collaborator_id    item_id
       1              1
       2              1
       3              1
       1              2
       4              2
```

So collaborator_id=1 worked with collaborator_ids=2,3 on item_id=1 and worked by themselves on item_id=2.

This seems super simple but I'm having a brain freeze on how to get these results. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query joins on the item_id and gets you all the unique collaborators who worked with a given collaborator on shared items, other than the collaborator himself:

```
SELECT distinct b.collaborator_id, b.item_id
FROM collab_table a
    JOIN collab_table b
    on a.item_id = b.item_id
WHERE a.collaborator_id = 1
    and b.collaborator_id != 1
```

Comment: -@davesnitty, how do i return `item_id` too?

Comment: @timpeterson just edited the query to do that.  You'll now potentially have multiple rows per collaborator, assuming a collaborator collaborated on >1 item.

Comment: hmm, your query's not quite right. It's returning this: http://i.imgur.com/W9aOY.png

Comment: @timpeterson That looks right to me if I understand your question correctly.  According to your data, collaborator #1 worked on items 1 and 2.  He worked on item 1 with collabs. #2 and #3.  He worked on item 2 with collab. #4.  The result screenshot shows that.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `subquery`

```
SELECT *
FROM collaborator
WHERE item_ID IN
(
   SELECT item_ID
   FROM collaborator
   WHERE collaborator_id = 1
) 
ORDER BY item_ID, Collaborator_ID
```

or by using `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   COLLABORATOR a
       JOIN COLLABORATOR b
          ON a.ITEM_ID = b.ITEM_ID
WHERE  b.COLLABORATOR_ID = 1
ORDER BY item_ID, Collaborator_ID;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26f9f/22)

Comment: -@JohnWoo, i just ran @davesnitty's code vs. your code and his code takes on average 0.6ms whereas your's takes 2ms. Do you see your code ever being faster than Dave's (like on a huge, million row collaborators table)? I accepted your answer b/c it made more sense to me, but obviously i'd like to pick the most performant code. Thoughts?

Comment: choose that best fits your answer always :D

Comment: My guess is that it's the join vs. the subquery and that as the dataset scales, joining on an indexed field would probably be the faster approach.  However, there are probably plenty of things that could affect the performance (indexing, config settings, etc.).

Comment: @davesnitty, i still don't really understand indexing. Is the JOIN you wrote "on an indexed field"? Just to be clear on my collaborators table, id is the primary key, auto-incremented field. I haven't assigned any other keys mainly cause I don't understand them.

Comment: @timpeterson Indexing tells the DB to create a data structure that enables faster lookups on a particular field (much like an index in a paper book allows you to look up a particular term without having to search page by page).  If you know you will be frequently using a field for joins, it may be good to create an index on it.  For instance "CREATE INDEX ind_itemid on collab_table(item_id)" would do this on your table.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: thanks dave, i generally understand the concept (book analogy makes sense to me) but why wouldn't one always do this? Will it slow down all other queries on the table (because a book **with** an index has more pages than a book **without** an index)? Also why does the JOIN benefit from indexing but the subquery does not? I changed to accepting your answer b/c you were first and your work here has led to the most insight.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is join the table back to itself, using your filter on one of the aliases, and pulling the result set from the other:

```
select a.COLLABORATOR_ID, a.ITEM_ID
from COLLABORATOR as a
inner join COLLABORATOR as b on
    a.ITEM_ID = b.ITEM_ID
where b.COLLABORATOR_ID = 1
```